# Selecionar sexo com enum

Tags: enums, rails4, erb

Fiz o campo selecionar sexo dessa forma:

model:

```
enum sexo: [:feminino, :masculino, :desconhecido]



    def self.sexes_for_select
        sexos.keys.map{ |x| [x.humanize, x] }
    end
```

form:

```
<%= f.select :sexo, Pessoa.sexes_for_select %>
```

O problema é que nao consigo adicionar a opção selecionar sexo, alguém? =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer adicionar um `prompt` no select, basta adicionar essa opção no `f.select`, da seguinte forma:

```
<%= f.select :sexo, Grupo.sexes_for_select, prompt: 'Selecionar sexo' %>
```